# In the node-inspector Chrome UI, how to have the "Call Stack" pane collapsed by default?

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

Each time the node inspector reloads, the Call Stack pane expands. I usually don't need this pane and it takes up valuable visual real estate, so I manually collapse it each time. How to default it to be collapsed?

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: no, i have not yet